# How to use AND and OR operands at the same time in Twitter API?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to retrieve the tweets which contain words like wall clock, wall paper, wall stickers using tweepy filter option. I know that 'space' means AND and ',' means OR.

Official doc I've referred: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track

In the docs example given `'twitter api,twitter streaming'` should get the following tweets.

```
1. The Twitter API is awesome
2. The twitter streaming service is fast
3. Twitter has a streaming API
```

Is there any way to combine both of these operands.

For eg: `"twitter api,streaming"` should retrieve all the above tweets.

I tried this approach

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)

stream.filter(track=['stream.filter(track=['twitter api,streaming'])'])
```

Its only getting the tweets which either contain streaming or twitter api. But not the way I wanted.

Comment: @Gaurav Shankar. I've given the snippet of code where the logic applies already. Anyway I've shared the code.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to have `twitter OR api OR streaming` without the comma. This method will give you all 3 that you listed.

Now if you want twitter api or twitter streaming like that then do the following: `"twitter api" OR "twitter streaming"`.  This will give you 1 and 2 from your list, not 3.

For more information check out [Query Operators](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)

To be clear about the `and` and `or`, `and` does not have to be explicitly specified as far as twitter is concerned for the following reason:

> watching now  -- containing both “watching” **and** “now”. This is the default operator.

Please note that this is different from using `"watching now"` which implies "watching" has to be immediately followed by the word "now".

However, `or` does have to be specified:

> love **OR** hate --   containing either “love” **or** “hate” (or both).

Comment: I think 2nd one will come under the output as it has both the words twitter and streaming. Correct me if im wrong.  And my question is how can i combine both AND and OR operands together.

Comment: I updated my comment to be more clear, let me know if it is.

Comment: In your answer "watching" and "now" dont have to come together in a tweet to be considered. "watching now" indicates that both words must be present in the tweet dont not have be present next to each other.

Comment: For "watching" and "now" both words **must** be present in a tweet. "watching now" **have** to be next to each other. From twitter docs: `“happy hour” -- containing the exact phrase “happy hour”.` hence the word exact phrase.

Comment: In https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track  check the twitter api,twitter streaming example.

Comment: I understand, that's the one you posted on there. In that example "twitter api,twitter streaming", in summation, it's saying: twitter and api and streaming. That's why they were able to get all 3 results.

Comment: I'm still not clear with your answer. Acc to your logic - "Twitter has a streaming API" shouldnt be considered as both twitter and streaming is not next to each other

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong. (twitter AND api) OR (twitter AND streaming)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82214/discussion-between-leb-and-karthik-zorfy).

Comment: `and` is a default operator in twitter, you don't need to specify it. To get "Twitter has a streaming API" you just need to type `twitter streaming` if you including double quotes i.e. `"twitter streaming"` you will not get the previous statement. `twitter api OR twitter streaming` will suffice